# Can't Edit or Update Room database entries

Tags: java, android, android-intent, mvvm, android-room

I am building an app where the user can store his/her usernames and passwords. The app has a simple UI. The Main thread has a list of entries, a FAB and a delete all icon on the action bar. My issue is that I am not able to edit and update existing entries.

I have the following code in the `onCreate()` of my `MainActivity.java`. When the user holds an entry, it launches the `AddEditEntry.java` activity. What happens here is that the launched activity does not have the existing entry data in its `EditText` fields:

```
adapter.setOnItemLongClickListener(new RecyclerViewAdapter.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemLongClick(Entries entries) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddEditEntry.class);
                intent.putExtra(AddEditEntry.EXTRA_USERNAME, entry.getUsername());
                intent.putExtra(AddEditEntry.EXTRA_HINT, entry.getHint());
                intent.putExtra(AddEditEntry.EXTRA_PASSWORD, entry.getPassword());
                intent.putExtra(AddEditEntry.EXTRA_ID, entry.getId());
                startActivityForResult(intent, EDIT_ENTRY_REQUEST);
            }
        });
```

In my `AddEditEntry.java` activity, I have the following code in the `onClick` of the save button. I am adding the new data as extras to the intent:

```
saveEntry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent data = new Intent();
                data.putExtra(EXTRA_USERNAME, usernameEditText.getText().toString());
                data.putExtra(EXTRA_HINT, hintEditText.getText().toString());
                data.putExtra(EXTRA_PASSWORD, passwordEditText.getText().toString());

                int id = getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_ID, -1);

                if(id != -1){data.putExtra(EXTRA_ID, id);}

                setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

and back in my `MainActivity.jav`, this is my `onActivityResult()`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == ADD_ENTRY_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        String username = Objects.requireNonNull(data).getStringExtra(AddEditEntry.EXTRA_USERNAME);
        String password = Objects.requireNonNull(data).getStringExtra(AddEditEntry.EXTRA_PASSWORD);
        String hint = Objects.requireNonNull(data).getStringExtra(AddEditEntry.EXTRA_HINT);

        Entries entry = new Entries(username, hint, password);
        viewModel.insert(entry);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Entry added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }else if(requestCode == EDIT_ENTRY_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        int id = Objects.requireNonNull(data).getIntExtra(AddEditEntry.EXTRA_ID, -1);
        String username = Objects.requireNonNull(data).getStringExtra(AddEditEntry.EXTRA_USERNAME);
        String password = Objects.requireNonNull(data).getStringExtra(AddEditEntry.EXTRA_PASSWORD);
        String hint = Objects.requireNonNull(data).getStringExtra(AddEditEntry.EXTRA_HINT);

        if (id == -1){Toast.makeText(addEditEntry, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}

        Entries entry = new Entries(username, hint, password);
        entry.setId(id);
        viewModel.update(entry);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Entry updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    else{Toast.makeText(this, "Entry not added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
}
```

When I run the app and try to edit an entry, the Toast message reads "Entry updated!" so it does run that code but the changes do not exist. I tried stopping the app and restarting it to refresh it but it still doesn't exist.

ViewModel.java:

```
public class EntryViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private EntryRepository repository;
    private LiveData<List<Entries>> allEntries;


    public EntryViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        repository = new EntryRepository(application);
        allEntries = repository.getAllEntries();
    }

    public void insert(Entries entries){repository.insert(entries);}

    public void update(Entries entries){repository.update(entries);}

    public void delete(Entries entries){repository.delete(entries);}

    public void deleteAll(){repository.deleteAllEntries();}

    public LiveData<List<Entries>> getAllEntries() {return allEntries;}
}
```

EntryRepository.java:

```
public class EntryRepository {
    private EntryDAO entryDAO;
    private LiveData<List<Entries>> allEntries;

    public EntryRepository(Application application){
        EntryDatabase database = EntryDatabase.getInstance(application);
        entryDAO = database.generateDao();
        allEntries = entryDAO.getAllEntries();
    }

    public void insert(Entries entries){new InsertEntryAsyncTask(entryDAO).execute(entries);}

    public void update(Entries entries){new UpdateEntryAsyncTask(entryDAO).execute(entries);}

    public void delete(Entries entries){new DeleteEntryAsyncTask(entryDAO).execute(entries);}

    public void deleteAllEntries(){new DeleteAllEntriesAsyncTask(entryDAO).execute();}

    public LiveData<List<Entries>> getAllEntries(){return allEntries;}


    public static class InsertEntryAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Entries, Void, Void>{
        private EntryDAO entryDAO;

        private InsertEntryAsyncTask(EntryDAO entryDAO){this.entryDAO = entryDAO;}

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Entries... entries) {
            entryDAO.insert(entries[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static class UpdateEntryAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Entries, Void, Void>{
        private EntryDAO entryDAO;

        private UpdateEntryAsyncTask(EntryDAO entryDAO){
            this.entryDAO = entryDAO;
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Entries... entries) {
            entryDAO.update(entries[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static class DeleteEntryAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Entries, Void, Void>{
        private EntryDAO entryDAO;

        private DeleteEntryAsyncTask(EntryDAO entryDAO){this.entryDAO = entryDAO;}

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Entries... entries) {
            entryDAO.delete(entries[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static class DeleteAllEntriesAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        private EntryDAO entryDAO;

        private DeleteAllEntriesAsyncTask(EntryDAO entryDAO){this.entryDAO = entryDAO;}

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            entryDAO.deleteAllEntries();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

EntryDAO.java:

```
@Dao
public interface EntryDAO {

    @Insert
    void insert(Entries entries);

    @Update
    void update(Entries entries);

    @Delete
    void delete(Entries entries);

    @Query("DELETE FROM entries_table")
    void deleteAllEntries();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM entries_table")
    LiveData<List<Entries>> getAllEntries();
}
```

Entries.java:

```
@Entity(tableName = "entries_table")
public class Entries {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;

    private String username, hint, password;

    public Entries(String username, String hint, String password){
        this.username = username;
        this.hint = hint;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Entries(){}

    public int getId() {return id;}

    public void setId(int id) {this.id = id;}

    public String getUsername() {return username;}

    public void setUsername(String username) {this.username = username;}

    public String getHint() {return hint;}

    public void setHint(String hint) {this.hint = hint;}

    public String getPassword() {return password;}

    public void setPassword(String password) {this.password = password;}
}
```

This is the `onCreate()` of my `AddEditEntry.java` class.  I've added the following Toast messages to see if it was receiving the data at all and turns out it doesn't.  The Toast messages were empty:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_addedit_entry);

        usernameEditText = findViewById(R.id.username_field);
        passwordEditText = findViewById(R.id.password_field);
        hintEditText = findViewById(R.id.hint_field);

        passwordABCD = findViewById(R.id.upp_checkbox);
        passwordabcd = findViewById(R.id.low_checkbox);
        password0123 = findViewById(R.id.num_checkbox);
        passwordSymbols = findViewById(R.id.sym_checkbox);

        radio4 = findViewById(R.id.four);
        radio8 = findViewById(R.id.eight);
        radio12 = findViewById(R.id.twelve);
        radio16 = findViewById(R.id.sixteen);

        Button generatePassword = findViewById(R.id.btn_password_generate);
        Button saveEntry = findViewById(R.id.btn_save);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        if(intent.hasExtra(EXTRA_ID)){
        setTitle("Edit Entry");
        usernameEditText.setText(Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getExtras()).getString(EXTRA_USERNAME));
        passwordEditText.setText(Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getExtras()).getString(EXTRA_PASSWORD));
        hintEditText.setText(Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getExtras()).getString(EXTRA_HINT));

        Toast.makeText(this, "Info Received!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(this, Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getExtras()).getString(EXTRA_USERNAME), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(this, Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getExtras()).getString(EXTRA_PASSWORD), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(this, Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getExtras()).getString(EXTRA_HINT), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
        else{setTitle("Add Entry");}

        generatePassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {passwordEditText.setText(generatedPassword());}});

        saveEntry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent data = new Intent();
                data.putExtra(EXTRA_USERNAME, usernameEditText.getText().toString());
                data.putExtra(EXTRA_HINT, hintEditText.getText().toString());
                data.putExtra(EXTRA_PASSWORD, passwordEditText.getText().toString());

                int id = getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_ID, -1);

                if(id != -1){data.putExtra(EXTRA_ID, id);}

                setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: please share your viewmodel

Comment: @Qasim Just did.  Check the edit.

Comment: also please paste your `EntryRepository` as well as DAO impl

Comment: Also done.  Check the edits.

Comment: @oo92 how do you know your database updated. your update DAO returning void so change its return type to int

Comment: Why int?  It could return a string as well.

Comment: Btw @SaurabhBhandari the issue isn't with the update method in my DAO.  The issue is that, when I long hold an item, the existing entry is not passed through the intent because EditText fields in `AddEditEntry.java` do not show the values for the existing entry

Comment: @SaurabhBhandari Just did.  Added toast messages in `onItemLongClick()` for each entry passed and the toast messages read the data as it is.  So the data is being passed.

Comment: Check the edit.  It is the last piece of code.  Basically the `onCreate()` of my `AddEditEntry.java` class.  The Toast messages appear empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this

In your `MainActivity.java`

```
    ....
    ....
    adapter.setOnItemLongClickListener(new RecyclerViewAdapter.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemLongClick(Entries entries) {
            entry = entries;  // this is very important, entry holds the current edited item
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddEditEntry.class);
            intent.putExtra(AddEditEntry.EXTRA_USERNAME, entry.getUsername());
            intent.putExtra(AddEditEntry.EXTRA_HINT, entry.getHint());
            intent.putExtra(AddEditEntry.EXTRA_PASSWORD, entry.getPassword());
            // no need to pass the id, it's a autogenerated field 
            // intent.putExtra(AddEditEntry.EXTRA_ID, entry.getId());
            startActivityForResult(intent, EDIT_ENTRY_REQUEST);
        }
    });

    ....
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {

        if(requestCode == ADD_ENTRY_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            ...
            ... 
        } else if(requestCode == EDIT_ENTRY_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // in an Edit operation, id should not be modified, so, no need to pass this parameter 
            // int id = 
            // Objects.requireNonNull(data).getIntExtra(AddEditEntry.EXTRA_ID, -1);
            String username = Objects.requireNonNull(data).getStringExtra(AddEditEntry.EXTRA_USERNAME);
            String password = Objects.requireNonNull(data).getStringExtra(AddEditEntry.EXTRA_PASSWORD);
            String hint = Objects.requireNonNull(data).getStringExtra(AddEditEntry.EXTRA_HINT);

            // entry already exists, so, no need to create a new one            
            //Entries entry = new Entries(username, hint, password);
            //entry.setId(id);
            entry.setUsername(username);
            entry.setPassword(password);
            entry.setHint(hint);
            viewModel.update(entry);

            Toast.makeText(this, "Entry updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Entry not added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Other remarks...

In your `RecyclerViewAdapter.java`

```
    // This is not needed. Your list is already created in your Room query
    //private List<Entries> entries = new ArrayList<>();

    private List<Entries> entries;
```

In your `MainActivity.java`

```
    // This is not needed
    // AddEditEntry addEditEntry;
    ....
    ....
    // addEditEntry = new AddEditEntry();
```

Comment: Check the edit to see the `Entries.java` class.  This approach might not work.

Comment: Why not? Just implements Serializable to your Entries class,

Comment: Where are you getting `entries.get(position)` from?

Comment: I assume that `entries` is your query list passed to your `recyclerView` adapter.

Comment: Nope.  Entries are just submissions into different EditText fields.  They're not passed as a list.

Comment: Weird. Your RecyclerView adapter needs a list to populate their items.

Comment: It does but `entries.get(position)` still doesn't work.  https://github.com/oo92/CryptPass is where the entire project is located in.

Comment: ok, I see. In your `Adapter` you have a public function to do that. Replace `entries.get(position)` by `adapter.getEntryAt(position)`. Don't forget to make your `Entries` serializable. Then, you should pass the whole entry to your AddEdit activity. So, don't care about the `id` value.

Comment: My `onItemLongClick()` doesn't have `int position` parameter.  Where did you get that from?

Comment: In your Adapter, you have defined an `OnItemLongClickListener` interface. You should modify it to send the position instead of the whole list.

Comment: It isn't a simple modification.  It breaks the entire code:  With my old approach, the edit page was getting `Bundle[mParcelData.dataSize=308]` when I was trying to pass the intent extras.

Comment: Ok, Let me edit my answer to help you maintain your current approach. The goal is to pass the current item position in ' onLongClick' event to be sure to update the selected item.

Comment: I already have `private List<Entries> entries = new ArrayList<>();` in my `RecyclerViewAdapter`

Comment: Also, didn't work.  The only difference is `Bundle[mParcelData.dataSize=340]` instead of `308`.

Comment: `List<Entries> entries = new ArrayList<>();`   Yes, but you don't need to write `new..`. Just `List<Entries> entries;`.

Comment: I just write a similar test program and it works. You added `entry = entries;`in `onItemLongClick ` ?

Comment: Yep.  Did you refer to the github repo?

Comment: - Yes, the github repo.

Comment: I did add `entry = entries;` in `onItemLongClick`

Comment: ok, anyway. I suppose it's because of EXTRA_ID parameter. You use it to refill your values in AddEditEntry.